# Spring Security Authenticates User with old credentials until Web App Restart

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, authentication, caching, spring-security

Hi there I am developing a web app and I am using Spring Security. In the app the user can change his/her details (username, password and some other fields). I am using a **custom User Details Class** for this and my Spring Security **configuration is the default** (keep in mind no cache method is declared, so I suppose **NullUserCache** is used). All the user records come from *DataBase* using **JDBC Connector** (MySQL).

Now when a user changes his/her info or/and username-password those changes update the corresponding columns in DataBase. **So now the DB is updated**. Because I have not implemented setters in my Custom User Details Class, I force the user to logout log out automatically. **But** now he/she can login using **both the new** username **and the old** one.

Suppose now that the user changed something on the other fields (for example if the age was changed from 20 to 21). When user **logins using the new** username I can see **21**. If user **logins using the old** username I can see **20**!.
I guess Spring Security now creates a new User (during login) which didn't exist and the old one is **never removed**!

So after reading many posts in the web and trying the corresponding solutions I 'm still unable to fix that.

What I have used (in the controller that is responsible for account editing):

```
    if (authenticate != null){
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, authenticate);
    }
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

What I understand and believe is that Spring Security holds somewhere (I thought User Cache) the username, maybe along with the password and now it sees the old username as a different User. The only way to prevent this from happening is to restart the app. **After restarting** the user **only** logins using the **new** username.

Is there any way I can remove that "user"-username? Any suggestion would be usefull, I am really confused and the only case close to mine was [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/89117-password-change-only-takes-effect-after-restarting-web-app) but his problem was with the oracle connector using connection cache..

**UPDATE** problem tracked down to a problem inside loadbyusername method..read more on the 14th comment below :)

Happy coding!

Comment: Try annotate your dao layer with `@Transactional`  and `@Repository`.

Comment: I already have `@Repository` in the DAO class which is responsible for the login. I do **not** have `@Transactional`..do you mean I should annotate the DAO class which is rensposible for updating the DB tables? It is a class with 5-6 methods..
Excuse me if my questions sounds silly but I am confused with all those I read in the web, moreover I do not really know if what I have used is really neaded..I mean `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);` and all those stuff

Comment: Login and update user info are on different DAOs..

Comment: annotate the dao class with `@Transactional` no matter how many methods it has.

Comment: `HttpServletRequest.logout()` can be used to logout the current user.
You can use it when a password change request comes.

Comment: When the user changes the username, does the old username still exist in the database?

Comment: @Jebil hey thanks for your reply..unfortunatelly `@Transaction` didn't help..Can you please explain me what exactly `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();` does?I know it is obviously, it clears the securutycontext info but does it have to do with the fact (I suppose) that spring security still "remembers" the user authentication username-password and does not use the Dao which is responsible for the login, so it does not see that this user does not exist anymore?

Comment: @Rob Winch yeap it does not exist anymore. I use an update query which look like.. `UPDATE table_name SET username = newusername WHERE username = oldusername` (yes I use prepared statements, I wrote it like that here just to be easier to understand). Just to be sure I run a select query through workbench just to be sure..
As I said its not a DB problem..if I stop the web app and restart it then the old username does not validate which is good..so somehow (maybe there is something missing) Security still remembers that this username is still validated..I do not use cached connection with JDBC..

Comment: Can you try authenticating afterwards with an incognito window? Also when you authenticate both times (i.e. prior to renaming the username and after) does it reach your custom UserDetailsService? Finally, can you provide the debug logs for when you authenticate after the rename?

Comment: Oh dear god how silly I feel now..1)what do you mean incognito window?Uknown window?You mean if the "old user" can access a page that needs authentication?2)What I can really say is that it uses the **Dao for login** because I have a system out with the query and it does show it on the 1st login and on the 2nd,3rd login (new username, old username corespondigly). 3) Debug logs..err I 'll just have to read on how to do that :$ Can you please confirm that if after the update has been done the code in my question should do the trick?Is that code in the end enough for "forgetting" the "old" user?

Comment: Oh and I am sure I have not created a cookie (nor have implemented a remember me feature) Spring Security is version 3.1

Comment: @Robin Winch Sir I think I found something intresting..During the Dao for login returns a `Map<String, userdetails> repository` . After username change has happened, user is redirected to logout page. (I confirmed through Workbench + Jdbc query that old username does not exist anymore) now that method of dao does not enter the if condition (as expected) `if (resultset != null && resultset.next())` and goes to the else which has nothing..so it returns an empty repository. As now I see inside **userdetails service** it should throw `UsernameNotFoundException` but it does not!! Continue below..

Comment: **userdetails service** contains the loadbyusername method which contains the following..`userdetails user = (daoname.login(username)).get(username);
  if(user == null){
   throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found..");
  }
  return user;`
Shouldn't I see that exception when I login with the old username that does not exist?

Comment: Ok I found the black hole :P although after username change has happened and the user is redirected to the login page..assume he tries to login with the old one..then the dao for login is called as it should BUT userdetails service does NOT throw sernameNotFoundException as it should..the question is why? **Dao enters the empty else** (because resultset is null). Now how on earth does userdetails user = (daoname.login(username)).get(username); does not equal null?

Comment: Ok finally bug confirmed to be the fact that after every login the repository returned from the dao is appended, so after 5 different users login it contains 5 different keys. If a user changes his username then the old one will exist on this repository.So I think of 5 possible solutions..1) after every login before accessing the DB that HashMap should be empty first (delete all content). 2) Delete with a method the old value. Question: multiple users are supposed to use the app..Do they share the same instance of dao?I mean if before login the HashMap gets empty does other users have problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the source of that problem..black hole closed. Credits @Jebil and @Robin Winch for their help!

Well everything worked as it should except the fact that the HashMap on the rensposible for the login DAO, was never cleared..so after every successful login attempt the HashMap returned was appended and so after every username update, it contained both old and new values..solution was simple..before accessing the DB HashMap should be cleared!

Happy dividing by 0 :P